# Pandas Fill rows missing in date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that represents a hotel reservations by date:

```
date        volume  city
2020-01-05      10    NY
2020-01-06      10    NY
2020-01-07      30    NY
```

The Dataframe is ultimately being written to the Database and because of that I need to have a complete range of `dates` from a given point in the past to a given point in the future, for example, the Dataframe (for entire 2020) I need should look like this:

```
date        volume  city
2020-01-01       0    NY
2020-01-02       0    NY
2020-01-03       0    NY
2020-01-04       0    NY
2020-01-05      10    NY
2020-01-06      10    NY
2020-01-07      30    NY
...
2020-12-31       0    NY
```

It's important that all the rows filling the range have a `volume=0` and the city is repeated in the entire dataset.

How can I effective convert my Dataframe to fill dates missing in the range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with replace missing values to `0`, for column `city` set `NY`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

r = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
df = df.set_index('date').reindex(r).fillna({'volume':0}).assign(city = 'NY')
print (df)
            volume city
2020-01-01     0.0   NY
2020-01-02     0.0   NY
2020-01-03     0.0   NY
2020-01-04     0.0   NY
2020-01-05    10.0   NY
           ...  ...
2020-12-27     0.0   NY
2020-12-28     0.0   NY
2020-12-29     0.0   NY
2020-12-30     0.0   NY
2020-12-31     0.0   NY

[366 rows x 2 columns]
```

If possible multiple cities and need `date_range` for each city create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

r = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([r, df['city'].unique()], names=['date','city'])

df = df.set_index(['date', 'city']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
          date city  volume
0   2020-01-01   NY       0
1   2020-01-02   NY       0
2   2020-01-03   NY       0
3   2020-01-04   NY       0
4   2020-01-05   NY      10
..         ...  ...     ...
361 2020-12-27   NY       0
362 2020-12-28   NY       0
363 2020-12-29   NY       0
364 2020-12-30   NY       0
365 2020-12-31   NY       0

[366 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This works great. What can I do if I need to backfill NaN values from a column with the first value encountered. I think something like `df = df.set_index('date').reindex(r).fillna({'volume':0, city:df['city'].iloc[0]}).assign(city = 'NY')` but I'm getting a different column type